# The following golang code deadlocks. Could someone help in understanding why?

Tags: concurrency, go

This example is taken from http://blog.golang.org/pipelines. It runs and gives correct answer but it shows following runtime error: "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!". Could anyone help me understand why this is happening? 
    package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func gen(nums ...int) <- chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            out <- n
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func sq(in <- chan int) <- chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for n := range in {
            out <- n * n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func main() {
    for n := range sq(gen(2,3)) {
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
}
```

However the following modification doesn't.

```
func main() {
    // Set up the pipeline.
    c := gen(2, 3)
    out := sq(c)

    // Consume the output.
    fmt.Println(<-out) // 4
    fmt.Println(<-out) // 9
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for n := range in` of the `sq()` function never exits, and start blocking (after reading 2 values), because `gen()` never closed its channel.
Adding `close(out)` to the `go func` of `gen()` would make it work: [see playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dcmiIWwFXV).

With channel, the receiver blocks until receiving a value.
[The range keyword, when used with a channel, will wait on the channel until it is closed](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.fr/2011/06/channels-in-go-range-and-select.html).

`sq()` is blocked, which means `close(out)` is never called, and in turn `main()` blocks on `range sq()` (since the channel `sq` isn't closed).

In your second example, `main()` itself exits, which means even though `sq()` is blocked, everything still stops.